# $ionicModal focusFirstInput not working on ios devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using angularjs and ionic framework for html5 mobile app. The scenario is when user clicks the search box on main page. A modal should load up autofocusing the searchbox input field and cancel button inline. Also when the searchbox in Modal autofocuses on input field, it should also open up the ios keyboard. 
Right now what is happening is when I click on searchbox on main page, it opens up the modal with search header and cancel button and also autofocuses on search input field.It is working fine on desktop view. But the autofocus feature is not working properly on ios devices and also the keyboard doesn't pop-up when modal loads up.

Acc. to ionic  docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/ I am using

```
focusFirstInput: true
```

for autofocus to work.

Here is the plunker [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/YAPzL9b2V3jBcH9ebF0b) that I created which works fine on desktop but not on iphone 4 and 5.

Please, Let me know how can I make this work on ios and android devices.

Also, as a side question, if anyone knows about a good chrome or safari pluggin to test the application for mobile devices that will be helpful. I know in chrome we can use their emulate feature to test the responsive designs but what pluggin to use if we want to fully test the mobile application.

Comment: Seems to work on the latest beta14